# How to determine actual memory occupied by Query Cache in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, memory, query-cache

How can we check if the MySQL server is utilizing high memory/RAM ?

How much memory is occupied in total by query cache ? How much memory is fragmented ?

Basically what is occupying xGB off memory by MySQL server ?

**Currently running MySQL Server version 5.7.25.**

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'QC%'; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'query_c%';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses the amount specified by `query_cache_size`.

If that value is more than about 50M, then it is probably slowing down the server.

The Query cache is going away; it cannot be used in any Clustering setup, and it has been removed from MySQL 8.0.

*Every* modification to a table triggers a purge of *all* entries for that table.  Therefore the QC, especially a big one, is costly in busy production servers.

If you must use the QC, follow these tips:

- No more than 50M (except on Aurora)
- Use `SQL_CACHE` or `SQL_NO_CACHE` in each `SELECT`, based on whether the query is likely to be repeated before it is purged.

(A small percentage of production system *do* benefit from the QC.)

There are cryptic metrics in `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Qc%';` but I can't explain them.

Comment: query_cache_size=1M for me. But still as query_cache_type=0 (off), non of the queries were getting cached. But, i suspect some kind of memory fragmentation happened around the QC.
After FLUSHING QC, memory consumption came down by 10GB. But now, it has starting rising again.
So, is there any way of checking the fragmented memory or MySQL memory footprint ?

Comment: @PrateekPande - Is the OS using "huge pages"?  If not, RAM is broken up into 4KB pages; no fragmentation possible.

Comment: If `query_cache_type = 0`, you may as well set `query_cache_size = 0`.

Comment: See OS routines `top` and `innotop`.

Comment: query_cache_type = 0, you may as well set query_cache_size = 0
this was already done.